# IIS Pausing the SMTP Service what will happen?

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-6

If I pause the SMTP service in IIS 6 what will happen to any new mails that are sent? Will they just sit in the pickup folder untill it us turned on or are the rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the emails are being placed there by an application, they'll sit there until the SMTP service is restarted.